# WebPart which displays a list with information about pages: What is the best way to search/filter this list

Tags: search, caml-query, publishing-page, fast-search, enterprise-search

I have a webpart, which displays a list with information (title, creation date) about publishing pages under the current web site.

Above this list there should be a search form (filter) to search this pages for the given search string.

What is the best way (performance etc.) to search? A simple CAML-Query with "Contains"-Keyword or using the sharepoint enterprise/fast search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is difference between Filter and Search.

Using CAML, you query the list. It can be performance intensive if your list is too large.Also, you should be aware of throttle limits(5000 items).

Using Search, you query already indexed information which is better performance wise.

Newly added pages will be available in search results only after crawling Whereas you can find them using CAML as soon as they are published.